# Get Bound Event Handler in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, events, tkinter

After a bind a method to an event of a Tkinter element is there a way to get the method back?

```
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> frame = Tkinter.Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
>>> frame.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: pprint('Click')) # function needed
>>> frame.pack()
>>> bound_event_method = frame.???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associated call to do that for the tk C API would be [Get_GetCommandInfo](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_Tcl_GetCommandInfo.htm) which

> places information about the command
>   in the Tcl_CmdInfo structure pointed
>   to by infoPtr

However this function is not used anywhere in [_tkinter.c](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Modules/_tkinter.c) which is the binding for tk used by python trough [Tkinter.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/lib-tk/Tkinter.py).

Therefore it is impossible to get the bound function out of tkinter. You need to remember that function yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to do this in Tcl/Tk is trivial: you use the same bind command but without the final argument.

```
bind .b <Button-1> doSomething
puts "the function is [bind .b <Button-1>]"
=> the function is doSomething
```

You can do something similar with Tkinter but the results are, unfortunately, not quite as usable:

```
e1.bind("<Button-1>",doSomething)
e1.bind("<Button-1>")
=> 'if {"[-1208974516doSomething %# %b %f %h %k %s %t %w %x %y %A %E %K %N %W %T %X %Y %D]" == "break"} break\n'
```

Obviously, Tkinter is doing a lot of juggling below the covers. One solution would be to write a little helper procedure that remembers this for you:

```
def bindWidget(widget,event,func=None):
    '''Set or retrieve the binding for an event on a widget'''

    if not widget.__dict__.has_key("bindings"): widget.bindings=dict()

    if func:
        widget.bind(event,func)
        widget.bindings[event] = func
    else:
        return(widget.bindings.setdefault(event,None))
```

You would use it like this:

```
e1=Entry()
print "before, binding for <Button-1>: %s" % bindWidget(e1,"<Button-1>")
bindWidget(e1,"<Button-1>",doSomething)
print " after, binding for <Button-1>: %s" % bindWidget(e1,"<Button-1>")
```

When I run the above code I get:

```
before, binding for <Button-1>: None
 after, binding for <Button-1>: <function doSomething at 0xb7f2e79c>
```

As a final caveat, I don't use Tkinter much so I'm not sure what the ramifications are of dynamically adding an attribute to a widget instance. It seems to be harmless, but if not you can always create a global dictionary to keep track of the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear to be... why not just save it yourself if you're going to need it, or use a non-anonymous function?

Also, your code doesn't work as written: `lambda` functions can only contain expressions, not statements, so `print` is a no-go (this will change in Python 3.0 when `print()` becomes a function).

Comment: Cristian used pprint, which is okay for a lambda.