# Tkinter - Limit Tab Sequence To The Focused Frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When repeatedly pressing the TAB key while running the code below you'll note that the focused entry widget cycles through all the entry widgets.  I would like to know if there's a simple way to make the tab only cycle through the entry widgets in the "selected frame".

```
import tkinter as tk
class Frame_Tab:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x350')
        self.root.title('Frame Tab')
        self.dg = '#c0c0c0'
        self.bg = '#54ed58'
        self.lg = '#c9c9c9'

        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,highlightcolor=self.bg,highlightthickness=3,highlightbackground=self.dg,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.f1heading = tk.Button(self.frame1,text='Frame 1',takefocus=0,bg=self.lg,fg='black',height=1,borderwidth=5,command=lambda:self.f1e1.focus(), relief=tk.RAISED,font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1heading.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,ipadx=10)
        self.f1l1 = tk.Label(self.frame1,text='Frame1 Entry1',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1l1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f1e1 = tk.Entry(self.frame1,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1e1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f1l2 = tk.Label(self.frame1,text='Frame1 Entry2',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1l2.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f1e2 = tk.Entry(self.frame1,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1e2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5)

        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,highlightcolor=self.bg,highlightthickness=3,highlightbackground=self.dg,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.frame2.pack(pady=10)
        self.f2heading = tk.Button(self.frame2,text='Frame 2',takefocus=0,bg=self.lg,fg='black',height=1,borderwidth=5,command=lambda:self.f2e1.focus(), relief=tk.RAISED,font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2heading.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,ipadx=10)
        self.f2l1 = tk.Label(self.frame2,text='Frame1 Entry1',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2l1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f2e1 = tk.Entry(self.frame2,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2e1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f2l2 = tk.Label(self.frame2,text='Frame1 Entry2',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2l2.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f2e2 = tk.Entry(self.frame2,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2e2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f2l3 = tk.Label(self.frame2,text='Frame1 Entry3',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2l3.grid(row=3,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f2e3 = tk.Entry(self.frame2,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2e3.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5)

        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Frame_Tab()
```

Comment: I don't see see nothing cycles. I'm using windows10 python 3.12.0b3

Comment: @toyotaSupra The entry widget that has focus changes with each TAB.  I would like the the cycle or sequence of the selected entry widgets to remain in the frame that is selected.

Comment: If I pressed frame1, you want Entry get focus and press enter again then go to next Entry foucus?

Comment: @toyotaSupra Press Frame1 and you will see that 'Frame1 Entry1' gets focus.  Press TAB and you see 'Frame1 Entry2' gets focus.  Press TAB again and you will see that the focus goes to 'Frame2 Entry1' - I would like it to cycle back to 'Frame1 Entry1, thus staying in the frame that had focus.  I have a solution that I will post shortly, but it is somewhat of a hack.

Comment: OIC. I understood.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371372/how-can-i-unbind-every-single-binding-from-a-tkinter-root-window

Comment: @toyotaSupra Thanks for your responses, but I still don't think you understand what I'm wanting.  I've posted some code below that is somewhat of a hack, but it accomplishes what I wanted.  I don't know why, but I can't get the code block to format correctly - maybe you can edit and fix it.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

OK, I give up on trying to get this revised code to format correctly! SMH (THANKS for the code format edit)

I have found a solution, but it is somewhat of a hack. The code below is the same as above with the following changes:

1. I create a list of ALL Entry widgets in the applications

   self.allEntry = [self.f1e1,self.f1e2,self.f2e1,self.f2e2,self.f2e3]
2. I then bind each Entry widget to the FocusIn event. The binds call a function applicable to the Frame the Entry widget is in (self.set1 or self.set2)
3. I then define set1, set2, and setTakeFocus - each of these functions can be found near the end of the code below and should be self-explanatory.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
class Frame_Tab:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x350')
        self.root.title('Frame Tab')
        self.dg = '#c0c0c0'
        self.bg = '#54ed58'
        self.lg = '#c9c9c9'

        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,highlightcolor=self.bg,highlightthickness=3,highlightbackground=self.dg,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.f1heading = tk.Button(self.frame1,text='Frame 1',takefocus=0,bg=self.lg,fg='black',height=1,borderwidth=5,command=lambda:self.f1e1.focus(), relief=tk.RAISED,font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1heading.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,ipadx=10)
        self.f1l1 = tk.Label(self.frame1,text='Frame1 Entry1',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1l1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f1e1 = tk.Entry(self.frame1,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1e1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f1e1.bind('<FocusIn>',self.set1)
        self.f1l2 = tk.Label(self.frame1,text='Frame1 Entry2',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1l2.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f1e2 = tk.Entry(self.frame1,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1e2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f1e2.bind('<FocusIn>',self.set1)

        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,highlightcolor=self.bg,highlightthickness=3,highlightbackground=self.dg,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.frame2.pack(pady=10)
        self.f2heading = tk.Button(self.frame2,text='Frame 2',takefocus=0,bg=self.lg,fg='black',height=1,borderwidth=5,command=lambda:self.f2e1.focus(), relief=tk.RAISED,font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2heading.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,ipadx=10)
        self.f2l1 = tk.Label(self.frame2,text='Frame1 Entry1',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2l1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f2e1 = tk.Entry(self.frame2,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2e1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f2e1.bind('<FocusIn>',self.set2)
        self.f2l2 = tk.Label(self.frame2,text='Frame1 Entry2',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2l2.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f2e2 = tk.Entry(self.frame2,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2e2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f2e2.bind('<FocusIn>',self.set2)
        self.f2l3 = tk.Label(self.frame2,text='Frame1 Entry3',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2l3.grid(row=3,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f2e3 = tk.Entry(self.frame2,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2e3.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f2e3.bind('<FocusIn>',self.set2)

        self.allEntry = [self.f1e1,self.f1e2,self.f2e1,self.f2e2,self.f2e3]
        self.root.mainloop()

    def set1(self,e=None):
        keep = [self.f1e1,self.f1e2]
        self.setTakeFocus(keep)

    def set2(self,e=None):
        keep = [self.f2e1,self.f2e2,self.f2e3]
        self.setTakeFocus(keep)

    def setTakeFocus(self,keep):
        for e in self.allEntry:
            if e in keep:
                e.config(takefocus=1)
            else:
                e.config(takefocus=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Frame_Tab()
```

Comment: Worked nicely. Thank I was googling for an hour.

Answer (score 1):

This will lead to usability problems if your users only use the keyboard, since it will make it impossible to traverse to the next frame unless you provide some way for the user to switch frames.

That being said, the simplest solution might be to simply add a custom binding for the last widget in each group to move the first to the first widget in the group.

For example, the following function will make it so that pressing tab in the second widget that is passed in will move focus to the first, and pressing shift-tab in the first will move focus to the second.

```
def _set_tab_bindings(self, w1, w2):
    w2.bind("<Tab>", lambda event: w1.focus_set() or "break")
    w1.bind("<Shift-Tab>", lambda event: w2.focus_set() or "break")
```

You can then call this in the code that creates each frame.

```
self._set_tab_bindings(self.f1e1, self.f1e2)
self._set_tab_bindings(self.f2e1, self.f2e3)
```

This might not be the most elegant solution, but arguably it's the most straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at your solution.  In reality this actual application runs on a Raspberry Pi with a 10" touch screen.  The app includes its own keypad which has Tab & Shift Tab keys.  Thanks again

Comment: It will work on RPi.

Answer (score 0):

(this only works for versions 3.9 and below) I did that by simply binding last entry widgets by "Tab FocusOut". So if tab has been pressed and it focused out, you focus on the first entry widgets. So Just add that two lines:

```
self.f1e2.bind("<Tab> <FocusOut>", lambda refocus: self.f1e1.focus())
self.f2e3.bind("<Tab> <FocusOut>", lambda refocus: self.f2e1.focus())
```

Seems to work for me. Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
class Frame_Tab:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x350')
        self.root.title('Frame Tab')
        self.dg = '#c0c0c0'
        self.bg = '#54ed58'
        self.lg = '#c9c9c9'

        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,highlightcolor=self.bg,highlightthickness=3,highlightbackground=self.dg,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.f1heading = tk.Button(self.frame1,text='Frame 1',takefocus=0,bg=self.lg,fg='black',height=1,borderwidth=5,command=lambda:self.f1e1.focus(), relief=tk.RAISED,font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1heading.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,ipadx=10)
        self.f1l1 = tk.Label(self.frame1,text='Frame1 Entry1',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1l1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f1e1 = tk.Entry(self.frame1,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1e1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f1l2 = tk.Label(self.frame1,text='Frame1 Entry2',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1l2.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f1e2 = tk.Entry(self.frame1,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f1e2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f1e2.bind("<Tab> <FocusOut>", lambda refocus: self.f1e1.focus())  # there

        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.root,highlightcolor=self.bg,highlightthickness=3,highlightbackground=self.dg,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.frame2.pack(pady=10)
        self.f2heading = tk.Button(self.frame2,text='Frame 2',takefocus=0,bg=self.lg,fg='black',height=1,borderwidth=5,
                                   command=lambda:self.f2e1.focus(), relief=tk.RAISED,font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2heading.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,ipadx=10)
        self.f2l1 = tk.Label(self.frame2,text='Frame1 Entry1',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2l1.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f2e1 = tk.Entry(self.frame2,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2e1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f2l2 = tk.Label(self.frame2,text='Frame1 Entry2',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2l2.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f2e2 = tk.Entry(self.frame2,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2e2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f2l3 = tk.Label(self.frame2,text='Frame1 Entry3',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2l3.grid(row=3,column=0,pady=5)
        self.f2e3 = tk.Entry(self.frame2,width=8,bg='white',fg='black',font=('Arial',12))
        self.f2e3.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5)
        self.f2e3.bind("<Tab> <FocusOut>", lambda refocus: self.f2e1.focus())  # and there

        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Frame_Tab()
```

Comment: As for me it doesn't work

Comment: This is strange. I just can copy paste code without any changes and it is working. It is working if you press just Tab. Will not work for shift tab, as l didn't make a function for this

Comment: @DanyaK Your code does not work for me either.  The TAB key continues to cycle through both frames with no regard to which on has Focus, but thanks for the try.

Comment: @DanyaK Your code actually works if I remove the <Tab> from your bind statements.  Please edit your code and I'll be glad to give it an up vote and accept it.

Comment: @DanyaK, oops, I just found an issue.  If Frame2 Entry3 has focus and I click the Frame 1 button, I have to click it twice.  The 1st click sets focus back to Frame2 Entry1 (as expected by your code) a 2nd click gets me back to Frame 1.

Comment: @Pragmatic_Lee Yes, I have added "Tab" in order to make sure you pressed tab and so focused out. I will try to figure this out, because I can't understand, how the same code could work differently for two people.

Comment: @DanyaK  FWIW I'm testing this on Windows 10 Python V3.10.9 Tkinter V8.6

Comment: @Pragmatic_Lee yes, that was the case, my fault. Mine version was a little bit old, so it worked on it. This is not wotking on a new anymore. Then you better use Bryan's answer above, it is similar, but will definitely work.